# Hand-made interface to SWD to write flash of ARM chip

Tags: arm, swd

I'm interested in creating simple interface to SWD to be able to write flash memory of ARM chips. I.e. to create a make-shift programming device - more for sake of exercise.

I started reading the documentation and searching for examples (for I think people already tried this). Currently I have a few questions, for which I would be thankful for guidance:

- I'm going to configure SWDCLK as normal output, and SWDIO as an open-drain (acting as input when it is in high-Z, see below) - I suspect that it is also open-drain on the side of the target device, so with the help of pull-up I will never have a short-circuit by mistake - is this correct?
- is there minimum allowed clock period? or anything will do, even just a few Hertz? Or perhaps this is dependent on target device?
- is it correct that in waiting mode both lines are driven HIGH on the host side, and when the communication begins, the first edge on SWDCLK is falling?
- HOST should change SWDIO on falling edge of SWCLK - and sample data from target (when needed) on falling edge of SWCLK either - right?

I think currently that's enough (though I would be also thankful for short sample of commands sequence to read / write the flash - but I believe I'll find it out anyway soon) - thank you in advance!

Currently I'm trying to use Arduino to create a basic prototype, though I can switch to plain Atmega or LPC111x with FTDI cable at any time... Though I believe this is not important.

P.S. to explain better about SWDIO - with AVR's for example I put the pin to LOW state and then if it is switched to output, it produces 0. However if it is switched to input, it is in high-Z state and really works as input. I.e. I manipulate not PORTx bit, but DDRx instead (while PORTx is permanent 0 and PINx is used for reading).

Answer (score 4):

> I'm going to configure SWDCLK as normal output, and SWDIO as an open-drain

SWDCLK is OK, but SWDIO is bidirectional and not open drain. That means you must be able to switch from output to input mode and vice versa.

> is there minimum allowed clock period?

Usually not, but some devices have minimum clock rates for special functions like unlocking.

> I would be also thankful for short sample of commands sequence to read / write the flash

That is specific for each device. [OpenOCD](http://openocd.org/) supports many different types (both microcontrollers and programmers) and has source code available.

I have already ported [Versaloon](https://github.com/versaloon/versaloon) to the LPC1343 MCU on the CCC [R0ket](https://github.com/turboj/versaloon-r0ket), this might be a simpler starting point.

Comment: "but SWDIO is bidirectional and not open drain" - oh, I poorly explained my idea, I'll update the description. Thank you for all your hints!

Comment: If power consumption and speed aren't important, it's possible to use a resistor rather than a 3-state driver to interface an output to an I/O pin.  When the I/O pin is driving a signal, it wins.  When it's floating, the resistor-tied output wins.  It's generally not hard to find a resistor which is high enough to avoid damaging the output but low enough to overpower any parasitic leakage.  Parasitic capacitance may limit the usable speed, but for a manual interface that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: BTW, I've never switch-programmed a processor serially, but I have used a group of 8 data switches, 8 LEDS, some mode switches, and a button, to to feed a 16-byte short program into an RCA-1801 processor.